# python module to get current geolocation without using coordinates or address as argument

Tags: python, geolocation

I want to get my current address using GPS and without providing any coordinates or address in the method as arguments. So is there any way in python I can do it?. I have tried reverse and geocode method but they require query as argument.

Comment: ...so, what data are you planning on using to get the current location? IP address?

Comment: GPS does not broadcast addresses. So getting the location from GPS and then getting the address of the location are two separate tasks that will require two separate steps using most libraries. But nothing will keep you from chaining them in your own utility function, so that your other code can do both steps in one.

Comment: anything which will give me appropriate location

Comment: i Have got the coordinates in html on client site now i need to pass them to python in django,so plz suggest if u know any way i can do it